# Three parts, four words

Tags: riddle, wordplay

One of us describes my ability to call the dead
Another describes my physical appearance
And the other one describes my state of freedom
Sort us, and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A person who can talk to the dead, or who can transmit messages from the dead, is often called a

> medium.

As for physical appearance,

> size

is an attribute of that, and

> "small"

is one possible value.

The term

> "at large"

describes a state of freedom, as opposed to a state of incarceration.

Sorted by their (inter-related) other meanings, those three parts produce the four-word phrase:

> "small medium at large".

([From the joke](http://theoatmeal.com/djtaf/j/99), presumably.)

Comment: Quite fast! And yes, this is the answer. And I got the joke from imgur =)

Comment: It's an excellent joke.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be

> The Grim Reaper

One of us describes my ability to call the dead

> Reaper has that meaning.

Another describes my physical appearance

> Grim means dreadful, horrific.

And the other one describes my state of freedom

> This is hard to explain, but the article "the" suggests that there exists only one Grim Reaper and it's not bound to anything/anyone (it is not **my** Grim Reaper, it is not **your** Grim Reaper, it is not **his** Grim Reaper, it is **the** Grim Reaper!)

Comment: I'm not sure why is this downvoted. It is not the answer (as you can see you are struggling with the third clue), but I think it is a good try.

Comment: @justhalf I really have no idea why they do this, but I'm sure that I have some haters in Puzzling (they downvote my posts everyday, for no reason). Anyway, I'm glad that you appreciate my attempt :-)

Comment: The post's title says that the solution has four words, but your answer only provides three.